# python3 fabric import Error: cannot import Connection

Tags: python-3.x

```
import os
import string
from fabric import Connection
import configparser
import socket


config = configparser.RawConfigParser(allow_no_value=True)
configFilePath = r'/root/config.ini'
config.read(configFilePath)
puser = config.get('Server', 'user')
#print (puser)
db_server = list(config.items('Database'))
#print (db_server)


def host_connect():
    for key in db_server:
        print (key[0])
        conn = Connection(host="puser@{0}".format(key[0]))
        conn.run('ps -ef | grep postgres')
```

I am trying to run this code and getting error as
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "psql_cleanlogs.py", line 6, in 
    from fabric import Connection
ImportError: cannot import name 'Connection'

The same procedure I have done in different codes and it ran fine but here is it is creating troubles. I am using python3 virtual env

Answer (score 8):

I was facing a similar issue, I checked the downloaded `fabric` package contents, it didn't have `Connection.py` (maybe the wrong repo from where I downloaded the package). I installed `fabric2` from the correct repository (`https://pypi.python.org/simple`) and it worked.

```
from fabric2 import Connection
```